# Accessing parent method from a component received as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a reusable Confirmation component that renders a button and when clicked, it should open a Material UI Dialog. The button component gets passed in as a prop for the Confirmation component

`<Confirmation component={() => <MUIButton>Click me</MUIButton>} />`

The parent component looks like this

```
const Confirmation = ({ component: Component }) => {

  const handleClick = () => {
    ...logic to open the dialog...
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Component onClick={handleClick} <-- how to trigger this? />
      <Dialog />
    </>
  )
}
```

Now how would I get this to work without having to specify the `onClick` in the passed button component itself? For this situation one can assume the component passed as a prop is always some kind of a button.

```
<Confirmation
  component={() => (
    <MUIButton
      onClick={...logic} <-- don't want to have to specify this
    >
      Click me
    </MUIButton>
  )
/>
```

OR am I approaching this from a wrong perspective? Should this be solved by passing the button as a child instead? As in

```
<Confirmation>
  <MUIButton> Click me </MUIButton>
</Confirmation>
```

and how would the implementation be in this situation?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes you could have an `onClose` callback prop that the dialog calls to let the parent define your individual use case for closing the dialog. Mui Dialog should already have something to this effect

Comment: @JohnRuddell Didn't quite get it, mind adding a little code example?

Comment: if you [look at the documentation](https://mui.com/api/dialog/) for `Dialog` the component you're using... you can see they expose an `onClose` callback to handle closing the dialog. I would recommend sticking with this pattern so things are consistent.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I think you missed my point. Let's say the `handleClick` only had a `console.log` in it and in this example I know for sure the component being passed as a prop is always a button. Now how would I trigger the `onClick={handleClick}` when the button is clicked?

`<Component onClick={handleClick} />` nothing happens eventhough the Component is a button

`<Confirmation component={() => <MUIButton onClick={...do something}>Click me</MUIButton>}` now this does obviously work but all the logic is hidden in the `<Confirmation />` component so this would be unnecessary

Comment: Right, so use a HOC to handle calling the button. Essentially something like `withConfirmation` that pulls the `onClick` method from props and does whatever you'd like with it. This way when defining a component you just `export default withConfirmation(MyComponentHere)`. This HOC can also handle rendering the confirmation button, and when a user clicks it you then call the callback

Comment: @JohnRuddell Now this sounds better. I'll work on this later, thanks!

Comment: One other thing you may want to consider while doing this is to use React Context. It sounds like a good use case for this, you can put your confirm component function as well as the click handlers... etc inside React context. This way you dont need a direct parent to child relationship for the props to get passed. I can probably show you a few examples later when you're getting to it if you'd like

Comment: @JohnRuddell withConfirmation HOC ended up being a perfect solution for this case, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! feel free to write up the solution as an answer so others can see the solution :) I'll give you a vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by creating a higher order component as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69800608/accessing-parent-method-from-a-component-received-as-a-prop?noredirect=1#comment123382119_69800608) by John

```
const withConfirmation = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return (props) => {
    return (
      <>
        <WrappedComponent

          // Overrides the possible onClick logic passed as a prop
          onClick={ ...dialog opening logic }

          {...props}
        />
        <Dialog>
          ...
        </Dialog>
      </>
    );
  };
};
```

```
const Confirmation = withConfirmation(MuiButton)

<Confirmation>Clicking me opens a dialog</Confirmation>
```